# Spring Batch - Processor not running after initial run

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am using Spring boot 2.0.5.RELEASE and running a batch process using this:

```
# prevent auto-start of batch jobs
spring:
  batch:
    job:
      enabled: false
```

and triggering it manually using a controller end-point (in `input` are the parameters that are collection from user from the controller):

```
jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParametersBuilder()
                    .addDate("date", new Date())
                    .addJobParameters(new JobParameters(input)).toJobParameters());
```

Here is my batch configuration:

```
@Bean
public MongoItemReader<Document> reader() {
    MongoItemReader<Document> reader = new MongoItemReader<>();
    reader.setTemplate(mongoTemplate);
    reader.setCollection(XML_PERSIST_COLLECTION);
    reader.setQuery("{}");
    Map<String, Sort.Direction> sorts = new HashMap<>(1);
    sorts.put("status", Sort.Direction.ASC);
    reader.setSort(sorts);
    reader.setTargetType(Document.class);
    return reader;
}

@Bean
@StepScope
public MyItemProcessor processor() {
    return new MyItemProcessor();
}

@Bean
public MongoItemWriter<OutputDto> writer() {
    MongoItemWriter<OutputDto> writer = new MongoItemWriter<>();
    writer.setTemplate(mongoTemplate);
    writer.setCollection(RESPONSE_COLLECTION);
    return writer;
}

@Bean
public Step step() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step")
            .<Document, OutputDto> chunk(1)
            .reader(reader())
            .processor(processor())
            .writer(writer())
            .allowStartIfComplete(true)
            .build();

@Bean
public Job job(Step step) {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("job")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .flow(step)
            .end()
            .build();
}
```

and my processor:

```
public class MyItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<Document, OutputDto> {

    @Value("#{jobParameters['username']}")
    private String username;

    @Value("#{jobParameters['password']}")
    private String password;

    @Override
    public OutputDto process(final Document document) throws Exception {
        // implementation code
    }
}
```

I am using `@StepScope` for the *processor* to extract the job parameters that are passed from my controller.

---

**Issue:**
Everything is fine except that the batch job will run only once after the app starts and it will not run again (it runs, but I tried keeping debug points in *processor* and it is not getting there). I am already adding a *timestamp* job parameter so that the batch job can be run again, yet the *processor* is not running more than once (when it should). Any ideas?

Comment: Since you added a timestamp as a job parameter, a new job instance should be created for each run. Do you see a new job instance for each run in your job repository? If it's the case, I'm not sure how, in the subsequent runs, the reader/writer would be invoked but not the processor.

Comment: A new instance is being created, and I am getting the start / stop logs too, but subsequent runs do not invoke the processor :(

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your config (unless I'm missing a small detail), but if you share a minimal gist I can run to reproduce the issue, I would love to help.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine thanks a lot man, its fixed now. I tried adding `@StepScope` to the `reader()` and `writer()` as well and now the processor is getting invoked as expected :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `reader()` and `writer()` had *singleton* scope while the `processor()` had `@StepScope` - so looks like that's why the `writer()` was *not* getting invoked.

I added `@StepScope` to the reader and writer and now everything is working fine, though it didn't strike me as instinctive - should have worked without that in 2.0.5.RELEASE.